# seleccionar un elemento de subtabla datatable

Tags: datatables

Estoy trabajando con una subtabla de una datatable, hago click en una fila de la tabla y se me despliega otra tabla hija como fila de la primera tabla.
Tengo este comando que me funciona bien

```
idT = $(this).parent().siblings('td:first').text();
```

Me guarda el elemento que me interesa en la variable idT de la subtabla, el problema es que cuando yo oculto la columna, este valor ya no lo toma puesto que accede al text.

Hay alguna forma de tomar el valor de una fila con la columna oculta?

Por si puede interesar, pongo la solución

```
var data_formHis = tblT.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
```